# Cannot read property 'getTrackDrawable' of undefined

Tags: nativescript, react-native

Can someone please explain to me what is the issue here. When I am commenting simple code of switch it stops coming. Otherwise, it coming every time and crashing my android app.

`<Switch checked="{{globalShare}}" (checkedChange)="toggleGlobalShare($event)" offBackgroundColor="#F08080"  class="switch" horizontalAlignment="center"></Switch>`

Comment: will you please share the Share plugin npm repository name so that can check whole module( pluggin name)

Comment: tns-core-modules/ui/switch

Comment: I don't see a reason why it would crash, may be something to do in your code behind file or data model. Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing offBackgroundColor="#F08080" - I had the same & found this by a process of elimination. I have no explanation why it worked I'm afraid.